# Aren't these the same: "KEEP OUT" vs "DON'T ENTER" or "KEEP QUIET" vs "DON'T MAKE NOISE"?

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language, negation, imperative-sentences

I have seen on a door of a room **"KEEP OUT".** Apparently, they do not want people to enter the room.

But suddenly I reminded of other instances of "KEEP" being used as an positive imperative (rather than negative), such as **"KEEP QUIET"** instead of **"DON'T MAKE NOISE"** or **"KEEP FIT"** rather than "**DON'T GET FAT".** or "**KEEP AWAY"** rather than **"DON'T COME CLOSER".**

So, why make imperatives using the verb "KEEP OUT/CLEAR/FIT/AWAY etc." rather than saying the same thing "DON'T.....".

Comment: Remain outside the room - remain quiet etc. Two words is shorter than three for putting on signs!

Comment: It's idiomatic. You just have to accept it. Keep Out is for any space.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Don't" could be seen as authoratative and slightly rude sometimes. Using imperatives is not only shorter but more formal and understandable.

Comment: I don't see that  ordering someone to do something is any less rude than ordering them not to!